# How can you also get the error **instance** when do/catching specific error types?

Tags: swift, error-handling, do-catch

I love when simple things you think will take all of two minutes ends up taking over an hour!

When writing unit tests, we need to test for several specific error types, some of which have associated values.  We also need access to the error itself so we can unit-test the localized description.

The issue is, if you pattern-match on an error type, you can get the associated values, but you lose access to the error itself so you can't get things like `localizedDescription`, etc.

Here's the (over-simplified) code showing the two cases...

```swift
public enum MyError: LocalizedError {

    case missingKey(in: String, at: String.Index)
    
    public var errorDescription: String { "I Need To Get This Too" }
}
```

And here's how you can pattern-match to get only the error you're interested in, and it's associated values, but again, `error` is not available within your catch block so you can't also check the localized description.

```swift
do {
    throw MyError.missingKey(in: "A", at: "A".startIndex)
}
catch let MyError.missingKey(in: string, at: location) {
    // Got the string and location associated values,
    // but how do I get the localized description?
    print(string, location)
}
catch OtherErr {
    print(error)
}
```

Of course you can use the 'broad hammer' `catch` command, but that really is not advisable. It may catch something you weren't expecting, hiding it from you, meaning you now have to actively plan for handling such unexpected cases inside your own block, cluttering responsibilities.  All around a bad approach.

But it also works (sigh)...

```swift
do {
    throw Error.missingKey(in: "A", at: "A".startIndex)
}
catch {

    switch error {

        // Handle your specific case
        case let Error.missingKey(in: string, at: location):
            print(string, location, error.localizedDescription) // <-- Finally!!!

        // BUT... You're also now responsible to handle all unexpected errors
        // since your 'catch' case catches everything and there is no 'fallthrough'
        case OtherError:
            print(error)

        default:
            throw error
    }
}
```

So... is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> I really hope I am missing something obvious here

Indeed. Catching the error inside a simple default `catch` clause is a blunt instrument if all you want to do is receive the error itself into the `catch` block. You're just doing that because the default `catch` block gives you a name, `error`, for the error as a whole.

But you can attach your *own* name to the error as a whole as part of the error specification. So at the very least you could first funnel down to catching a specific type of error, giving it a local name, and then look inside the error.

Here's a parallel case. Posit this error type:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case oops(message: String)
    var extraInfo: String { "hello" }
}
```

Now consider this way of dealing with it:

```
do {
    throw MyError.oops(message: "yipes")
} catch let theError as MyError {
    if case let .oops(theMessage) = theError {
        print("the message is", theMessage)
        print("the extra info is", theError.extraInfo)
    }
} catch {
    print("it was some other error:", error)
}
```

Observe that the associated value and the property are in scope in the same place, which I believe is what you're after.

And if MyError has multiple cases, then inside the first `catch` just do a `switch` instead of my `if case`.

Comment: Not crazy that this still requires basically two types of checks... the outer case to get the 'enum' type, then a second switch inside to get the 'case' type, but at least it's now only a subset of all possible errors (i.e. the cases), which is an improvement.  If nothing else comes up as better, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.  Still surprised they don't just pass through the 'error' object, especially since again, not all information comes from pattern matching. Seems like an omission to me, but I'm sure there's some rationale behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something. In all three attempts you have a `do/catch` block that is handling all (both) error cases. Why is the 3rd option (which gives the needed info), undesirable compared to the other two attempts?

That aside, I think what you are trying to accomplish can be solved using your 3rd attempt by using `default:` so you only need to handle the desired errors instead of all errors.

```
do {
    throw Error.missingKey(in: "A", at: "A".startIndex)
}
catch {
    switch error {
        case let Error.missingKey(in: string, at: location):
            print(string, location, error.localizedDescription) // <-- Finally!!!
        default:
            break
    }
}
```